# error error: cannot find symbol class GithubRepoAdapter

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to java and android. I'm sure this is a basic question.
I get an error when trying to import a class defined in a file adjacent to the current file. The code is available at https://github.com/morenoh149/HarryLearnsAndroid/blob/master/HttpDemo/app/src/main/java/com/harrymoreno/httpdemo/MainActivity.java#L44

```
// MainActivity.java
package com.harrymoreno.httpdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import com.harrymoreno.httpdemo.GitHubRepoAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pagination_list);

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

        GithubClient client = retrofit.create(GithubClient.class);
        Call<List<GithubRepo>> call = client.reposForUser("morenoh149");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GithubRepo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {
                List<GithubRepo> repos = response.body();

                // error error: cannot find symbol class GithubRepoAdapter
                listView.setAdapter(new GithubRepoAdapter(MainActivity.this, repos));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
// GitHubRepoAdapter.java
package com.harrymoreno.httpdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class GitHubRepoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GithubRepo> {

    private Context context;
    private List<GithubRepo> values;

    public GitHubRepoAdapter(Context context, List<GithubRepo> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_pagination, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagination, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_pagination_text);

        GithubRepo item = values.get(position);
        String message = item.getName();
        textView.setText(message);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have spelling mistake on that error line.

It should be `GitHubRepoAdapter`, not `GithubRepoAdapter`.